# How to append "%.2X" data in char array or string in C (preferably) or C++?

Tags: c++, string, append

I have been trying to fix it for last 3 days, and tried many options, but didn't get to work. 
I have the following code in C++.

```
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <iphlpapi.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <typeinfo>
    #include <string>


    // Link with Iphlpapi.lib
    #pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #define WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE 15000
    #define MAX_TRIES 3

    #define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
    #define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

    /* Note: could also use malloc() and free() */

    int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
    {

        /* Declare and initialize variables */

        DWORD dwSize = 0;
        DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

        unsigned int i = 0;

        // Set the flags to pass to GetAdaptersAddresses
        ULONG flags = GAA_FLAG_INCLUDE_PREFIX;

        // default to unspecified address family (both)
        ULONG family = AF_UNSPEC;

        LPVOID lpMsgBuf = NULL;

        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = NULL;
        ULONG outBufLen = 0;
        ULONG Iterations = 0;

        PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pCurrAddresses = NULL;
        PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pUnicast = NULL;
        PIP_ADAPTER_ANYCAST_ADDRESS pAnycast = NULL;
        PIP_ADAPTER_MULTICAST_ADDRESS pMulticast = NULL;
        IP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS *pDnServer = NULL;
        IP_ADAPTER_PREFIX *pPrefix = NULL;

        // Allocate a 15 KB buffer to start with.
        outBufLen = WORKING_BUFFER_SIZE;
        std::string str;
        char Buffer[255];
        do {

            pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)MALLOC(outBufLen);
            if (pAddresses == NULL) {
                printf
                    ("Memory allocation failed for IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES         struct\n");
                //exit(1);
            }

            dwRetVal =
                GetAdaptersAddresses(family, flags, NULL, pAddresses,         &outBufLen);

            if (dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
                FREE(pAddresses);
                pAddresses = NULL;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

            Iterations++;

        } while ((dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) && (Iterations <         MAX_TRIES));

        if (dwRetVal == NO_ERROR) {
            // If successful, output some information from the data we         received
            pCurrAddresses = pAddresses;
            while (pCurrAddresses) {

                if (wcscmp(pCurrAddresses->FriendlyName, L"Ethernet") == 0)         {

                    if (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength != 0) {
                        printf("\tPhysical address: ");
                        for (i = 0; i < (int)pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddressLength;
                        i++) {
                            if (i == (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength         - 1)) {
                                printf("%.2X\n", (int)pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddress[i]);
                                //str.append(pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddress[i]);
                            //  str += (int)pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddress[i];
                                //sprintf(Buffer + strlen(Buffer), "%.2X",         (int)pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[i]);
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("%.2X-", (int)pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddress[i]);
                                //str.append(pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddress[i]);
                                //str += (int)pCurrAddresses-        >PhysicalAddress[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                pCurrAddresses = pCurrAddresses->Next;

            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Call to GetAdaptersAddresses failed with error: %d\n",
                dwRetVal);
            if (dwRetVal == ERROR_NO_DATA)
                printf("\tNo addresses were found for the requested         parameters\n");
            else {

                if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
                    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |         FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, dwRetVal, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,         SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                    // Default language
                    (LPTSTR)& lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL)) {
                    printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
                    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
                    if (pAddresses)
                        FREE(pAddresses);
                    //exit(1);
                }
            }
        }

        if (pAddresses) {
            FREE(pAddresses);
        }
        MessageBoxA(NULL, str.c_str(), "testx", MB_OK);
        system("pause");
        return 0;

            }
```

I want to print the mac address in MessageBox (winapi) using type LPCSTR at once, not in the loop, as it is happening now with `printf()`.
I then have to send the mac address in URL using `InternetOpenUrl()` which has the data type of LPCSTR or LPWCSTR, I'll do the rest, once I succeed in printing and storing mac address in `MessageBox` and LPCSTR format respectively.

EDIT: My question is:
1. How to append the value of mac address into char array or string in loop?
2. How to store the mac address in LPCSTR to display in MessageBox()?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A buffer for the whole string, `snprintf` the current value to a temporary buffer, and appending to the buffer in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char MAC[18] = {0};
if (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength != 0) {
    // a MAC is usually 6 bytes in size...
    sprintf(MAC, "%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X",
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[0],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[1],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[2],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[3],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[4],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[5]);
    printf("\tPhysical address: %s\n", MAC);
    str.append(MAC);
}
```

If you want to be "politically correct" then format the actual number of bytes reported by `PhysicalAddressLength` (which can technically be as high as 8):

```
char MAC[24] = {0};
if (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength != 0) {
    char fmt[] = "%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X:%.2X";
    if (pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength < 8)
        fmt[(pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddressLength * 5)-1] = 0;
    sprintf(MAC, fmt,
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[0],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[1],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[2],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[3],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[4],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[5]
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[6],
        pCurrAddresses->PhysicalAddress[7]);
    printf("\tPhysical address: %s\n", MAC);
    str.append(MAC);
}
```

Comment: I used `sprintf_s` and didn't append to `str`, and it worked!!! as expected. Thank you very much, this is very good website!!!